# Double integration with a coordinate transformation, show $\iint_R f(x,y) dA = \iint_Rf(r,\theta)a b r \space dr \space d\theta$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The transformation from Cartesian to elliptic coordinates can be given by;

$$x = ar \cos(\theta)$$
$$y = br \sin(\theta)$$

(i) Show that for the coordinate transformation given above,

$$\iint_R f(x,y) dA = \iint_Rf(r,\theta)a b r \space dr \space d\theta $$

(ii) Hence, or otherwise, find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces,
$$z = 1- \sqrt{\Big(\dfrac{x}{4}\Big)^2 + \Big(\dfrac{y}{2\sqrt2}\Big)^2}$$

and $$\dfrac{x^2}{4}-x + \dfrac{y^2}{2} = 0$$

and the planes $z = 0$ and $z = 1$.

> I've had a look through the double integral section in my textbook, and 'relevant' lecture notes, but I don't actually know how to do what it is asking in (i) or (ii). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For part (i), you simply change the function to the other coordinate system and make sure you keep track of the Jacobian along the way inside the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $x = x(r, \theta)$ and $y = y(r, \theta)$, thus 
   $$
   J = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
   a \cos \theta , \quad-a\sin\theta\\
     b\sin \theta, \quad b r \cos\theta
   \end{pmatrix},
   $$
   so $|J| = abr ( \cos^2\theta + \sin ^2 \theta)=abr.$
2. Note that the second quadratic form maybe rewritten as 
   $$
   \frac{(x-2)^2}{2^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1.
   $$
   Plug in $z=0$ and $z=1$ to the first form to find the range of $r$ and then the range of $\theta$.